# How can I make my button to properly show full description of one country after displaying countries

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have created a search bar for countries and I want to have a button next to the country names which will display one of my component which is responsible for showing more detail about the country. Currently, it shows more detail when there is only one result, how can show this after clicking the button?

```
const App = () => {
const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);
const [searchName, setSearchName] = useState("");

 useEffect(() => {
  axios
    .get(`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/${searchName}`)
   .then(response => {
     console.log(`>> Response: ${JSON.stringify(response)}`);

     setCountries(response.data);
   });
 }, [searchName]);

 const handleSearch = event => {
  setSearchName(event.target.value);
  };
  const Country = ({ capital, name }) => {
  return (
   <div>
     <p>
       {name}{" "}
       <button props={countries} onClick={showCountry}>
         show
       </button>
     </p>
     </div>
   );
   };
  const showCountry = props => {
  return (
   <SingleCountry
     name={props.name}
     capital={props.capital}
     population={props.population}
     languages={props.languages}
     flag={props.flag}
    />
  );
 };
const SingleCountry = ({ name, capital, population, languages, flag }) => 
{
  return (
   <div>
     <h3>{name}</h3>
     <p>capital {capital}</p>
     <p>population {population}</p>
     <h2>languages</h2>
     <ul>
       {languages.map(el => (
         <li>{el.name}</li>
       ))}
     </ul>
     <img src={flag} alt="OOPS" class="flag-image" />
   </div>
  );
 };
 const Countries = () => {
  if (countries.length === 0) {
   return <span class="results__label"> Search something </span>;
   }
  if (countries.length === 1) {
  return countries.map(c => (
    <SingleCountry
      name={c.name}
      capital={c.capital}
      population={c.population}
      languages={c.languages}
      flag={c.flag}
    />
  ));
  }

 return (
  <div>
    <span class="results__label"> Search Results: </span>
    <div>
      {countries.map(c => (
        <Country name={c.name} />
      ))}
    </div>
  </div>
  );
 };

return (
 <div>
   <div style={{ margin: "8px" }}>
     find countries <input onChange={handleSearch} />
   </div>
    <Countries />
   <div />
 </div>
 );
};
```

export default App;

https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-butterfly-uf0dw Here is a sandbox of my code

Comment: [Here is a working SandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-field-5p8ou) since OP's is not working (I fixed the issues with it).....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a flag using `useState()` to hide/show a country information.

```
const Country = ({ capital, name, population, languages, flag }) => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>
        {name}{" "}
        <button props={countries} onClick={() => setShow(!show)}>
          { show ? 'hide' : 'show' }
        </button>
        {show && // use show flag to conditionally render country info
          <SingleCountry
            name={name}
            capital={capital}
            population={population}
            languages={languages}
            flag={flag}
          />
        }
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  };
```

Lastly, pass all info when populating the countries.

```
{countries.map(c => (
  <Country name={c.name}
    capital={c.capital}
    population={c.population}
    languages={c.languages}
    flag={c.flag}
   />
))}
```

[See Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/wizardly-swirles-p7rmu)